# Nested dollar $ signs for sustitution

Tags: bash, ls

I want to avoid creating temporary variables and get `ls` element by index.

Here's what I tried so far

```
echo ${"$(ls)"[2]}
```

But I'm getting bad substitution error.

Comment: Parsing the output of `ls` is usually considered a bad practice. For instance, if a filename contains spaces, depending on your implementation, you may end up with a truncated filename. A `for` loop (possibly breaking out of the loop when your condition is met) might be a better idea. Could you clarify why you want to avoid creating temporary variables?

Comment: @MalteSkoruppa actually, I need to move one file to another location, but it has a long complicated name, so I want to access it by index. I don't know, but for my aesthetic, I prefer not to create temporary variables and think of names for them, that's why I'm looking for one-liner.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps

```
echo "${ls[2]}"
```

Comment: `ls` isn't my variable, but the bash's command that lists all files in the directory. As you might know, `$(ls)` allows to expand the output. So basically, I'm trying to access one element of the output list, i.e get file name by index.

Comment: I see, so does this work for you? > ls | awk 'NR==3 {print $1}'

Comment: Neat! Almost works. Is it possible to take into account that my file might have spaces in its name?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out myself. You can parse `ls` output with the `sed` like so

```
echo $(ls | sed '2q;d')
```

that it'll yield `2`nd line in my case. Note that it also supports files with spaces in its names.

Comment: Uh, no it doesn't support filenames with spaces. You'll at least need to quote the command substitution, `"$(ls | sed '2q;d')"` for that (compare `stat $(ls | sed '2q;d')` vs `state "$(ls | sed '2q;d')"` for files that do have spaces in the name. Also, what's the in the 2nd line may vary by locale, so you should probably use `LC_ALL=C ls ...`. And if you have some broken filename for which `ls` puts `?` in the output, this won't work. Using an intermediate array is the safest way, or your aesthetic may someday run into trouble.

Answer (score 0):

This is the kind of thing you should be doing with shell globs, rather than with the output of `ls`.

`*` will expand to a list of the non-hidden files in the current directory, in the same lexicographical order as the output of `ls` in your locale. In bash, you could either capture those in a named array:

```
files=( * )
```

then access the second item as `"${files[1]}"` (arrays are zero-indexed in bash); or use the shell's *positional parameters*

```
set -- *
```

and then access the second file simply as `"$2"`. (The positional parameter array `$@` is also zero-indexed, but the 0th element is reserved for the current program name.)

If you switch to `zsh`, you *could* do something more like what you want in a "one liner", using *glob qualifiers*:

```
echo *([2])
```

(arrays are 1-indexed in zsh by default) or perhaps better

```
print -r -C1 *(N[2])
```

See `man zshexpn` for details.